# No reception w/ QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, network-programming, qtcpsocket

I looked for examples everywhere, and I just can't seem to find a solution.

## Issue

So : I have this receiving class called DataReceiver. Basically, I just want to receive data from a TCP Socket on the localhost (127.0.0.1) network. It seems that I can write w/ this socket (I checked w/ the Wireshark software) but it looks like the program does not receive anything.

I placed a qDebug() statement in the onDataReceived QT SLOT. This slot does not seem to be triggered at any moment. I tried editing the mTcpSocket->readyRead() QT SIGNAL manually, and the slot is correctly called upon, which means that the signal is not emitted because the QTcpSocket doesn't receive anything (or at least I this so).

My computer is a Mac w/ macOS High Sierra. I scanned open ports, and found that 51470 & 50911 are open. Those are the ports I tested.

## DataReceiver class

The code for this class is the following :

#### datareceiver.h :

```
class DataReceiver : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // Con/Destructors
    explicit DataReceiver(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit DataReceiver(const QString &pSourceAddress,
                          const unsigned int &pSourcePort,
                          QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DataReceiver();

    // Network Management
    bool connectToHost(void);

    // Getters
    QVector<float> *getData(void) const;
    QTcpSocket *getTcpSocket(void) const;
    QString getSourceAddress(void) const;
    unsigned int getSourcePort(void) const;

    // Setters
    void setData(const QVector<float> *pData);
    void setSourceAddress(const QString &pSourceAddress);
    void setSourcePort(const unsigned int &pSourcePort);

signals:

public slots:
    void onConnect();
    void onDisconnect();
    void onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void onDataReceived();

private slots:

private:
    void decodeData(const QByteArray &pMessage);

    QTcpSocket *mTcpSocket;
    QString mSourceAddress;
    unsigned int mSourcePort;

    const unsigned int mDataSize = 30;
    QVector<float> *mData;
};
```

#### And the implementation : datareceiver.cpp

```
// Con/Destructors
DataReceiver::DataReceiver(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    mTcpSocket(new QTcpSocket(this)),
    mSourceAddress("127.0.0.1"),
    mSourcePort(51470),
    mData(new QVector<float>)
{
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < mDataSize; i++)
        mData->append(.0);
}

DataReceiver::DataReceiver(const QString &pSourceAddress,
                      const unsigned int &pSourcePort,
                      QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    mTcpSocket(new QTcpSocket(this)),
    mSourceAddress(pSourceAddress),
    mSourcePort(pSourcePort),
    mData(new QVector<float>)
{
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < mDataSize; i++)
        mData->append(.0);
}

DataReceiver::~DataReceiver(){
    mTcpSocket->disconnectFromHost();
    mTcpSocket->waitForDisconnected();
    delete mTcpSocket;

    delete mData;
}

// Network Management
bool DataReceiver::connectToHost(void){
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onConnect()));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnect()));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(onBytesWritten(qint64)));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onDataReceived()));

    qDebug() << "connecting...";

    //emit mTcpSocket->readyRead(); // For testing. We correctly trigger the onDataReceived slot

    mTcpSocket->open(QAbstractSocket::ReadWrite);
    mTcpSocket->connectToHost(getSourceAddress(), getSourcePort());

    if(!mTcpSocket->waitForConnected(1000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << mTcpSocket->errorString();
        return false;
    }
    mTcpSocket->write("Hello ?"); // Test
    return true;
}

// Getters
QVector<float> *DataReceiver::getData(void) const{
    return mData;
}

QTcpSocket *DataReceiver::getTcpSocket(void) const{
    return mTcpSocket;
}

QString DataReceiver::getSourceAddress(void) const{
    return mSourceAddress;
}

unsigned int DataReceiver::getSourcePort(void) const{
    return mSourcePort;
}

// Setters
void DataReceiver::setData(const QVector<float> *pData){
    // Not yet implemented
    Q_UNUSED(pData);
}

void DataReceiver::setSourceAddress(const QString &pSourceAddress){
    mSourceAddress = pSourceAddress;
}

void DataReceiver::setSourcePort(const unsigned int &pSourcePort){
    mSourcePort = pSourcePort;
}

// Public Slots
void DataReceiver::onConnect(){
    qDebug() << "connected...";
}

void DataReceiver::onDisconnect(){
    qDebug() << "disconnected...";
}

void DataReceiver::onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes){
    qDebug() << bytes << " bytes written...";
}

// Private Slots
void DataReceiver::onDataReceived(){
    // Not yet implemented, code is for testing
    qDebug() << "onDataReceived called !";

    while(mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable()){
        qInfo() << mTcpSocket->read(mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable());
        qDebug() << mTcpSocket->readAll();
    }
}

// Private Methods
void DataReceiver::decodeData(const QByteArray &pMessage){
    // Not yet implemented
    Q_UNUSED(pMessage);
}
```

The mData/mDataSize are here for future usage, and are thus to be ignored here.

## Sender

To send data, I tried using ***netcat*** :

```
cat testfile.txt | nc 127.0.0.1 51470
```

I also created a ***DataSender*** class, w/ the same structure as the DataReceiver class. 
According to Wireshark, both methods seem to write data via TCP.

### DataSender class

#### datasender.h

```
class DataSender : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // Con/Destructors
    explicit DataSender(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DataSender();

    // Network Management
    bool connectToHost(void);
    void sendData(void) const;

    // Getters
    QString getDestinationAddress(void) const;
    unsigned int getDestinationPort(void) const;

    // Setters
    void setDestinationAddress(const QString &pDestinationAddress);
    void setDestinationPort(const unsigned int &pDestinationPort);

signals:

public slots:
    void onConnect();
    void onDisconnect();
    void onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void onDataReceived();

private:
    QTcpSocket *mTcpSocket;
    QString mDestinationAddress;
    unsigned int mDestinationPort;
};
```

#### datasender.cpp

```
DataSender::DataSender(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    mTcpSocket(new QTcpSocket(this)),
    mDestinationAddress("127.0.0.1"),
    mDestinationPort(50911)
{

}

DataSender::~DataSender(){
    mTcpSocket->disconnectFromHost();
    mTcpSocket->waitForDisconnected();
    delete mTcpSocket;
}

// Network Management
bool DataSender::connectToHost(void){
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onConnect()));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnect()));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(onBytesWritten(qint64)));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onDataReceived()));

    qDebug() << "connecting...";

    mTcpSocket->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, true);

    mTcpSocket->connectToHost(getDestinationAddress(), getDestinationPort());

    if(!mTcpSocket->waitForConnected(1000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << mTcpSocket->errorString();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void DataSender::sendData(void) const{
    QByteArray lData("Hello, this is DataSender ! Do you copy ? I repeat, do you copy ?");

    QByteArray lTemp;
    QDataStream lData2(&lTemp, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    lData2 << lData.size();

    if(mTcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        mTcpSocket->write(lTemp); //write size of data
        mTcpSocket->write(lData); //write the data itself
        mTcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
    }
}

// Getters
QString DataSender::getDestinationAddress(void) const{
    return mDestinationAddress;
}

unsigned int DataSender::getDestinationPort(void) const{
    return mDestinationPort;
}

// Setters
void DataSender::setDestinationAddress(const QString &pDestinationAddress){
    mDestinationAddress = pDestinationAddress;
}

void DataSender::setDestinationPort(const unsigned int &pDestinationPort){
    mDestinationPort = pDestinationPort;
}

// Public Slots
void DataSender::onConnect(){
    qDebug() << "connected...";
}

void DataSender::onDisconnect(){
    qDebug() << "disconnected...";
}

void DataSender::onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes){
    qDebug() << bytes << " bytes written...";
}

void DataSender::onDataReceived(){
    // Not yet implemented, code is for testing
    qDebug() << "onDataReceived called !";

    //while(mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable()){
        //qInfo() << mTcpSocket->read(mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable());
        //qDebug() << mTcpSocket->readAll();
    //}
}
```

## Client side Main

```
// Main routine ---------------------------------
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // Initializing application.
    QApplication lApplication(argc, argv);

    CLIENT::DataReceiver dataReceiver;
    dataReceiver.connectToHost();

    return lApplication.exec();
}
```

## Server side Main

```
// Main routine ---------------------------------
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication lApplication(argc, argv);

    SERVER::DataSender lDataSender;
    lDataSender.connectToHost();
    lDataSender.sendData();

    return lApplication.exec();
}
```

## Behavior

Basically, when I run the **DataReceiver** class in the main, I get the following behavior :

```
connecting...
connected...
7 bytes written...       # This is the write("Hello ?") I inserted just for testing

# "connected..." may occur after "7 bytes written...", 
# I don't remember, I am not in front of my computer right now.
```

## Conclusion

I believe I have simply forgotten something important, or that there is something I do not know of. This is a personal project, so a little exterior insight would be welcome !

Thank you very much !

Clovel

Comment: Do you have an event loop running in your code? Sending data is one thing, but you didn't include the server part which sends to you. Your client class looks ok to me.

Comment: With this code, even I have questions// QTcpSocket  binds to a `QHostAdress` not a string?

Comment: Hi @user3606329. A thought the qApplication was the "while(1)" routine, but maybe it is not. I would need to check the behavior of the class w/ a while(true) loop to see if it changes anything. The server/sender part is either played by a DataSender class like this one or a netcat command. 

Hi Mohammad, QTcpSocket has several constructors, and you are refering to one of them. Among others, there are : 
QTcpSocket(const QString& Address, const int& port)
QTcpSocket(const QHostAddress& Address). 

By the way, one constructor of QHostAddress takes QString and int for arguments.

Comment: Aside from the problem here, is there a specific reason for using TCP over 127.0.0.1, rather than `QLocalSocket`?

Comment: Hi @TheDarkKnight. There is : I didn't know QLocalSocket existed. And In a (not so) soon future, another IP address will replace "localhost".

Comment: You question about not receiving data, but where's the code for the server that sends data when a connection is made?

Comment: As I said, I either use the **netcat** command or I use a **DataSender** class. I will edit my post now to show the **DataSender** class.

Comment: I'm probably missing something but... your `DataReceiver` class connects (successfully it would seem) to `127.0.0.1:51470`.  That would suggest there's something listening on `127.0.0.1:51470`.  The `netcat` command you show connects to the same address.  I suspect [`QTcpServer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html) might be more useful to you here.  Or... try running `nc` with the `-l` option *before* running your `DataReceiver` example.

Comment: Hi @G.M. . Actually, `DataReceiver` should be the listener... I think. And netcat or `DataSender` should be the "writers". Is my logic wrong ?

So `DataReceiver` should be listening to `127.0.0.1:51470` and `nc` or `DataSender` should be connecting to it. 

What does QTcpServer add to this ? Shouldn't I be able to simply use a Socket ? Like a file descriptor in non-Qt C/C++ programming ? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: It sounds as if [`QTcpServer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html) *is* what you want -- it will listen for connections on a specified address and notify you as/when those connections occur.  You can have a look at [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html).

Comment: Thanks @G.M. ! I will fool around with `QTcpServer` tonight when I get home. I will give feedback on that solution. Nonetheless, Isn't `QTcpSocket` a two way connection ? Can't it be used to read _AND_ write ? 

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) can communicate with another `QTcpSocket`, but in order for this to happen, an initial connection must be made, utilising a [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

It's not possible for a `QTcpSocket` to listen for an incoming connection. Instead, `QTcpServer` can be used (or [QLocalServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html), if using [QLocalSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html)).

The `QTcpSocket` is set to [listen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#listen) on a port for incoming connections and when a connection is made, will emit a signal to notify of the [newConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#newConnection). Calling [nextPendingConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection) returns the `QTcpSocket` for the server side, allowing it to communicate with client from the incoming connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification ! I implemented a QTcpServer, and it does work ! I tested it using the sames methods as before : `netcat` & the `DataSender` class I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

So this is OP, and here is the solution I implemented. I'd like to thank @TheDarkKnight & @G.M. for their clarifications.

## Solution

Instead of using a `QTcpSocket` for my `DataReceiver` class, I used a combination of `QTcpSocket` *AND* `QTcpServer`. Basically, the `QTcpServer` listens for new connections & set the `QTcpSocket` when a connection is made.

Then, the class simply connects the `QTcpSocket` signal `readyRead()` to a personal slot. Here is the implementation of the class :

## DataReceiver class

### datareceiver.h

```
class DataReceiver : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // Con/Destructors
    explicit DataReceiver(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit DataReceiver(const QString &pSourceAddress,
                          const unsigned int &pSourcePort,
                          QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DataReceiver();

    // Getters
    QVector<float> *getData(void) const;
    QTcpServer *getTcpServer(void) const;
    QString getSourceAddress(void) const;
    unsigned int getSourcePort(void) const;

    // Setters
    void setData(const QVector<float> *pData);
    void setSourceAddress(const QString &pSourceAddress);
    void setSourcePort(const unsigned int &pSourcePort);

signals:

public slots:
    void onConnect();
    void onDisconnect();
    void onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void onDataReceived();
    void onNewConnection();

private:
    void decodeData(const QByteArray &pMessage);

    QTcpServer *mTcpServer;
    QTcpSocket *mTcpSocket;
    QString mSourceAddress;
    unsigned int mSourcePort;

    const unsigned int mDataSize = 30;
    QVector<float> *mData;
};
```

### datareceiver.cpp

```
// Con/Destructors
DataReceiver::DataReceiver(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    mTcpServer(new QTcpServer(this)),
    mSourceAddress("127.0.0.1"),
    mSourcePort(51470),
    mData(new QVector<float>)
{
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < mDataSize; i++)
        mData->append(.0);

    connect(mTcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));

    if(!mTcpServer->listen(QHostAddress(getSourceAddress()), getSourcePort()))
        qDebug() << "<DataReceiver> Server could not start. ";
    else
        qDebug() << "<DataReceiver> Server started !";
}

DataReceiver::DataReceiver(const QString &pSourceAddress,
                      const unsigned int &pSourcePort,
                      QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    mTcpServer(new QTcpServer(this)),
    mSourceAddress(pSourceAddress),
    mSourcePort(pSourcePort),
    mData(new QVector<float>)
{
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < mDataSize; i++)
        mData->append(.0);

    connect(mTcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));

    if(!mTcpServer->listen(QHostAddress(getSourceAddress())), getSourcePort())
        qDebug() << "<DataReceiver> Server could not start. ";
    else
        qDebug() << "<DataReceiver> Server started !";

}

DataReceiver::~DataReceiver(){
    delete mTcpServer;

    delete mData;
}

// Getters
QVector<float> *DataReceiver::getData(void) const{
    return mData;
}

QTcpServer *DataReceiver::getTcpServer(void) const{
    return mTcpServer;
}

QString DataReceiver::getSourceAddress(void) const{
    return mSourceAddress;
}

unsigned int DataReceiver::getSourcePort(void) const{
    return mSourcePort;
}

// Setters
void DataReceiver::setData(const QVector<float> *pData){
    // Not yet implemented
    Q_UNUSED(pData);
}

void DataReceiver::setSourceAddress(const QString &pSourceAddress){
    mSourceAddress = pSourceAddress;
}

void DataReceiver::setSourcePort(const unsigned int &pSourcePort){
    mSourcePort = pSourcePort;
}

// Public Slots
void DataReceiver::onConnect(){
    qDebug() << "QTcpSocket connected...";
}

void DataReceiver::onDisconnect(){
    qDebug() << "QTcpSocket disconnected...";
    disconnect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onDataReceived()));
    disconnect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnect()));
}

void DataReceiver::onBytesWritten(qint64 bytes){
    qDebug() << bytes << " bytes written to QTcpSocket...";
}

void DataReceiver::onDataReceived(){
    // Not yet implemented, code is for testing
    qDebug() << "onDataReceived called !";

    while(mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable()){
        qInfo() << mTcpSocket->read(mTcpSocket->bytesAvailable());
        qDebug() << mTcpSocket->readAll();
    }
}

void DataReceiver::onNewConnection(){
    qDebug() << "onNewConnection called !";
    mTcpSocket = mTcpServer->nextPendingConnection();

    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),    this, SLOT(onDataReceived()));
    connect(mTcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onDisconnect()));
}

// Private Methods
void DataReceiver::decodeData(const QByteArray &pMessage){
    // Not yet implemented
    Q_UNUSED(pMessage);
}
```